# Does VB.NET have an empty statement?

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for an empty statement in VB.NET similar to this in C/C++:

```
;
```

My understanding is this is simply an empty statement that does nothing.  However, when I try to use a C# to VB.NET converter to gain some insight I am just given a blank line.  Is there something similar I can use besides empty space?

Comment: In what contex do you use `;` in your C# code?

Comment: Well, here's one:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C an expression becomes a statement when it is followed by a semicolon. The semicolon itself is just a statement terminator. The equivalent to a statement terminator in Visual Basic is a line break and the equivalent of an empty statement is an empty expression followed by a line break.

Your first example would look something like this.

```
Function ProcessMessage() As Boolean
    ...
End Function

Sub ProcessMessages()
    While ProcessMessage()
    End While
End Sub
```

Your second example would look something like this. Note however that `exit` is a keyword in Visual Basic, so we have to call the label something else.

```
Sub f()
    ...
    If done Then
        GoTo _exit
    End If
    ...
_exit:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

When I have to do a do-nothing line in VB.NET just like *"pass"* in Python, I use the following one liners:

The ***"Just 8-bits Used"***

```
Dim i As Byte = 0
```

***"The Shortest One"***

```
Dim i = 0
```

The ***"No Memory Used"***

```
If 1 <> 1 Then Dim i = 0
```

I suggest you to add a **"TODO / HACK / UNDONE"** comment so you can remember this line it's just a placeholder line and you can find it easily in your task list. Example:

```vb
' TODO: Add function logic
Dim i = 0
```

More info about [Creating task list comments HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I like the titles :D

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net does not have an empty statement, but you can easily add one (tested with .net 6.0):

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
public Module VbExtras       
    <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)> 
    Public Sub NextSentence() : End Sub
End Module
...
Public Class C1        
    Public function Method1() as Boolean
        If l > 0 Then
            If b IsNot Nothing Then NextSentence '' useful for precompiler work
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("filled")
        End If
        return False
    End Function
End Class
```